# Shared pointer to a static const object?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

For context, I am implementing a user access system where people can log in to my application.  The current logged in user is accessed by a pointer to a `CUser`:

```
std::shared_ptr<CUser> m_pCurrentUser;
```

When a user logs out, I want this pointer to point to a "default" user that I have declared as a static const:

```
static const CUser xDefaultUser(L"Default", L"password", CUser::EAccessLevels::eAnon);
```

My first question is whether or not applying static const to the default user object is correct. My reasoning is that it should never change (const) and that I want it available for the lifetime of the application (static).

The second question is how I should assign the default user as the `m_pCurrentUser`. Should I instead declare a `const shared_ptr<CUser>` instead of a straight up object?

Comment: It would be `std::shared_ptr<const CUser> m_pCurrentUser`, and you need a no-op deleter for your defaultUser.

Comment: If code sometimes needs to modify `*m_pCurrentUser`, this will be at least a huge danger, since modifying `xDefaultUser` is not allowed.  If not, use `shared_ptr<const CUser>` instead as Jarod suggested.

Comment: Shared ownership of the current logged in user sounds a bit odd to me. I would rather expect it to be uniquely owned by whatever handles the logging in and out.

Comment: One possibility would be to use a "default user" class whose instances aren't modifiable but still not `const`.

Comment: Perhaps you could store a _copy_ of `xDefaultUser` in `m_pCurrentUser` when no user is logged in.  Then you are insulated from all these details.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning pointer to static object to a `shared_ptr` is not a good idea. You will get memory corruption, since the ptr doesn't own this memory:

```
shared_ptr<CUser> ptr = &xDefaultUser;
ptr = nullptr; // crash
```

You could create `static const shared_ptr` with default object. In this case memory won't be corrupted. See my example bellow:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class User {
public:
    User(const std::string& name)
        : _name(name)
    {}
    ~User() { std::cout << "Bye, " << _name << std::endl; }
    void print() { std::cout << _name << std::endl; }
private:
    std::string _name;
};

static const std::shared_ptr<User> s_defaultUser = std::make_shared<User>("<default>");

class UserMgr {
public:
    UserMgr()
        : m_current(s_defaultUser)
    {}

    void MakeCurrent(std::shared_ptr<User> u) { 
        if (u) {
            m_current = u;
        } else {
            m_current = s_defaultUser;
        }
    }

    std::shared_ptr<User> GetCurrent() { return m_current; }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<User> m_current;   
};

int main() {
    UserMgr mgr;

    mgr.MakeCurrent(std::make_shared<User>("User 1"));
    mgr.GetCurrent()->print();
    mgr.MakeCurrent(std::make_shared<User>("User 2"));
    mgr.GetCurrent()->print();
    mgr.MakeCurrent(std::make_shared<User>("User 3"));
    mgr.GetCurrent()->print();
    mgr.MakeCurrent(nullptr);
    mgr.GetCurrent()->print();

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5cae15ef2dadae5)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Smart pointers `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` must *own* the object they point to, and they will delete it when it is no longer needed.

Of course you can always do:

```
m_pCurrentUser = std::make_shared(xDefaultUser);
```

nothing will break, by the pointer will hold a **copy** of your static const object. Only a raw pointer or a `weak_ptr` does not care for ownership.

So if you can accept the overhead of copying the static const object, go that way: you keep clean smart pointer processing.

If you cannot accept that, you will have to build a special class of smart pointer that normally behaves as a `shared_ptr` but would also be able not to destroy its pointed object under special circumstances. A *simple* way would be to have an `bool owner` member that should be tested just before deleting the pointer object. I am not sure of all the implication of it, so my advice is *refrain if you can*

Comment: Nitpick: They can have custom deleters, in which case they don't really have to own the memory.

Comment: @einpoklum: far from nitpick. My answer focuses on the smart pointer, while your comment suggests to switch the problem to the `CUser` class. Unsure whether it is really simpler to implement anyway...

Comment: @einpoklum Using a do-nothing deleter in `shared_ptr` is probably the sign of a serious design issue.

Comment: @curiousguy: Possibly, but the fact that doing something is not a good idea doesn't mean that it's impossible, so your use of "must" is slightly misleading IMHO. I'd say something like "should really", or "You should use them under the assumption that they must" or something similar.

Comment: @einpoklum It's possible to have a `shared_ptr` that doesn't do anything when the last copy is destroyed. But almost all the uses of that idiom will clash with the idea that making a copy of a `shared_ptr` guarantees that the target isn't destroyed, because the `shared_ptr` family manages it (and nobody else does).

Comment: @einpoklum "_so your use of "must"_" I did not write "must".

Comment: It's in the first sentence of your answer... :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about an accessor method?

```
const CUser* GetCurrentUser() 
{
  return (m_pCurrentUser == nullptr) ? &xDefaultUser : m_pCurrentUser.get();
}
```

It allows you to control the access to the user (e.g. in the non-`const` version you could return a copy or a null pointer) and it prevents you from having to solve bugs where you forgot to set `m_pCurrentUser` to the default user on logout and it ends up being null.

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra pointer "state" meaning "the user logged out", which is not the same as "uninitialized user" (which would be nullptr). You can use a std::variant to implement that (if you can use C++17, otherwise boost::variant should work too)

```
#include <memory>
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

struct LoggedOut{
    int operator*(){return 50;}
};


int main(){
    std::variant<std::shared_ptr<int>, LoggedOut> pCurrentUser(nullptr);
    {
        pCurrentUser = std::make_shared<int>(1);
        auto newuser = pCurrentUser;
    }
    std::cout<< *std::get<0>(pCurrentUser)<<"\n";

    auto logout = [](auto& p){ p=LoggedOut(); };

    logout(pCurrentUser);
    std::cout<<*std::get<1>(pCurrentUser)<<"\n"; //prints 50
    //std::cout<<*std::get<0>(pCurrentUser)<<"\n"; //runtime error: bad variant access                                                                                                                             
}
```

If you don't want to use the std::get you can easily hide them in a custom pointer class, which gives

```
#include <memory>
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

struct LoggedOut{
    int operator*(){return 50;}
};

template<typename T>
struct myPointer : public std::variant<std::shared_ptr<int>, LoggedOut>{
    using super =  std::variant<std::shared_ptr<int>, LoggedOut>;
    using super::variant;
    auto operator*(){ return std::get_if<0>(this) ? *std::get<0>(*this) : *std::get<1>(*this); }
};

int main(){
    myPointer<int> pCurrentUser(nullptr);
    {
        pCurrentUser = std::make_shared<int>(1);
        auto newuser = pCurrentUser;
    }
    std::cout<< *pCurrentUser<<"\n";

    auto logout = [](auto& p){ p=LoggedOut(); };

    logout(pCurrentUser);
    std::cout<<*pCurrentUser<<"\n";
    std::cout<<*std::get<0>(pCurrentUser)<<"\n"; //runtime error: bad variant access                                                                                                                               
}
```